# London Congestion Charge on A205

Tags: london, tolls

Do I need to pay congestion Charge?

I travelled from Bexleyheath to South west through A2, A205, A3, A316 onto the M3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you went from A2 to A3 on the A205 then here is your route superimposed on the London Congestion Charge map.

[image]

So the answer is: no charge.

Answer (score 2):

The congestion charge zone can be viewed [here](https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/driving/congestion-charge/congestion-charge-zone) and you can check if you need to pay by destination.

From [the other answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/147361/89966), you don’t need to pay a charge.